Cannot run Nessus service with docker compose?
I am using docker compose file to create an container Nessus with bind mount. It's work successfully with every folder in container exept /opt. (mount folder still work successfully but can't run the nessus service)
This is my docker compose file:
services:
 nessus_service:
  image: tenable/nessus:10.8.0-ubuntu
  restart: always
  container_name: nessus_container
  ports:
    - 3002:8834
  volumes:
    - /home/nessus:/opt

This is message when i docker compose up:

2024-10-03 07:07:41,681 INFO spawnerr: can't find command '/opt/nessus/sbin/nessus-service'
2024-10-03 07:07:41,681 INFO spawnerr: can't find command '/opt/scripts/configure_scanner.py'

My host is Oraclelinux 9.4, Docker version is 27.3.1 and Docker Compose version is 2.29.7

What is inside /home/nessus on your machine? Did you you perhaps mean to mount it at /opt/nessus instead?

I try to mount at /opt/nessus and no more error. The container logs now is: nessus_container  | 2024-10-03 07:26:54,208 INFO success: nessusd entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
But i can't open to: https://my_host_ip:3002

Edit your question with details about your machine and its Docker setup.

If the image installs software into /opt/nessus, mounting anything over /opt will hide it.  You should almost never mount anything over the image's code.  As you've written it, this question seems to be a little more about running prebuilt software than about writing code, and Stack Overflow might not be the right place to ask.
